# subtracting a certain row in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

So I have a 4 by 4 matrix. [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]]

I need to subtract the second row by [1,2,3,4]

no numpy if possible.  I'm a beginner and don't know how to use that

thnx

Comment: I'm assuming you're programming in Python?

Comment: oh yea i am.  it's python

Comment: Can you think of a way to do this with loops?

Answer (score 0):

With regular Python loops:

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]]
b = [1,2,3,4]
for i in range(4):
    a[1][i] -= b[i]
```

Simply loop over the entries in the `b` list and subtract from the corresponding entries in `a[1]`, the second list (ie row) of the `a` matrix.

However, [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) can do this for you faster and easier and isn't too hard to learn:

```
In [47]: import numpy as np
In [48]: a = np.array([[1,2,3,4],[2,3,4,5],[3,4,5,6],[4,5,6,7]])

In [49]: a
Out[49]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [2, 3, 4, 5],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])

In [50]: a[1] -= [1,2,3,4]

In [51]: a
Out[51]: 
array([[1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 1, 1, 1],
       [3, 4, 5, 6],
       [4, 5, 6, 7]])
```

Note that NumPy *vectorizes* many of its operations (such as subtraction), so the loops involved are handled for you (in fast, pre-compiled C-code).